# Android Location TimeStamp Conversion To C-Sharp DateTime

Tags: c#, android, datetime, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to convert an `Android Location.Time` (long) value into a `c-sharp DateTime` value in `Xamarin` however I'm getting into some issues trying some Unix conversion code with an exception thrown.

Does anyone have a working conversion routine for this?

Also preferably going back the other way as well just to test it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
double seconds = Location.Time / 1000;
DateTime utcConverted = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddSeconds(seconds).ToLocalTime();
```

Comment: Thank you @Jason, looks exactly what I am after.  Do you know how to convert from DateTime back to Android long timestamp value also?

Comment: something like: utcConverted.Subtract(new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,DateTimeKind.UTC)).TotalMilliseconds